# how to check duplicate names in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is the model I want fetch such records who's **first_name** and **last_name** will be same

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

I tried this check only **first_name** or *last_name* are same but i have to check both **first_name** and **last_name** are same.

this checks if last names are the same.

```
duplicates = Customer.objects.values('last_name')
                            .annotate(name_count=Count('last_name'))
                            .filter(name_count__gt=1)

queryset = Customer.objects.filter(last_name__in=[item['last_name'] for item in duplicates])
                            .values()
```

this checks if first_names are the same.

```
duplicates = Customer.objects.values('first_name')
                            .annotate(name_count=Count('first_name'))
                            .filter(name_count__gt=1)

queryset = Customer.objects.filter(first_name__in=[item['first_name'] for item in duplicates])
                            .values()
```

Any Help Will Be Appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why not mark `first_name` and `last_name` with `unique_together`?

Comment: Sorry sir for late reply. I am using **Django-2.0**.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the set of `first_name`s and `last_names`s which occur multiple times with:

```
duplicates = Customer.objects.values('first_name', 'last_name').annotate(
    name_count=Count('pk')
).order_by('first_name', 'last_name').filter(name_count__gt=1)
```

You can obtain all the `Customer`s with a duplicated `first_name`/`last_name` combination with:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

duplicate_values = Customer.objects.values('first_name', 'last_name').annotate(
    name_count=Count('pk')
).order_by('first_name', 'last_name').filter(name_count__gt=1)

duplicates = Customer.objects.filter(
    reduce(or_, [Q(first_name=v['first_name'], last_name=v['last_name']) for v in duplicate])
)
```

Note however that you can use [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) or since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2) a [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) to *enforce* that the values are together unique, like:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=['first_name', 'last_name'], name='uniquename')
        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution problem has been resoled.

Comment: Sir how i can fetch that duplicates record from Customer ??

Comment: `queryset = Customer.objects.filter(last_name__in=[item['last_name'] for item in duplicates], first_name__in=[item['first_name'] for item in duplicates]).values()`

Comment: `queryset = Customer.objects.filter( reduce(or_, [Q(first_name=v['first_name'], last_name=v['last_name']) for v in duplicates])).values()`